# Using the same action controller to render and save in yii2

Tags: yii2

the controllers actions of my yii2 application render and validate/save http input data. The first time (when the route was requested) it renders the form **but with errors** as follows:

[image]

I need to render form in the first time without error label. Is there way to solve this using the same action to render and save ?

This is my code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new CourseForm;
    $model->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post('CourseForm');

    if ($model->validate()) {
        // save...
    } else {
        return $this->render( 'create', [ 'model' => $model, 'errors' => $model->errors ]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use a default value to overcome this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are loading the attribute and calling the `validate()` every time the action is called and when the validation fails the view loads with the errors highlighted. So that pretty much makes sense why is it doing like that.

Secondly you can just use `$model->load()` and supply the `post()` array to it it will load the attributes automatically.

Your code can be reduced to the following and it will not show the error labels when the page loads untill unless you submit the form

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new CourseForm();
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
        // save...
    }
    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model, 'errors' => $model->errors]);

}
```